# Mouse connection to an ACER Aspire 1830T

Tags: mouse, connection

I am trying to connect my Apple wireless mouse to my *ACER Aspire 1830T* and I have looked so hard for the answer but I cant seem to find it.

I have

- looked into the ***handbook***
- asked computer geeks
- searched numerous websites

How do I connect the Apple wireless mouse to my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess you're using a magic mouse. It connects over bluetooth, and the good news is, your mouse should 'just work'

Instructions here are based off [microsoft's support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/952818) and [apple's support page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2845) - I've covered the basics here but they're worth reading through as well.

Go to control panel, bluetooth devices and select add (or the bluetooth icon on your taskbar). Switch your magic mouse on and off. It should be detected in your PC now - add it with the passcode 0000

There also seem to be [third party drivers](http://www.trackpadmagic.com/magic-mouse/help/driver-installation) that tell you things like battery level